# Maas setup with two networks. Node commissioning failed?

Tags: networking, server, maas, proxy, openstack

I am trying to setup MaaS with two networks. Master running 14.04.5 LTS with MaaS version 1.9.4. Ultimate goal is to deploy OpenStack cloud with 4 nodes

**Network 1 -- 10.0.X.X -- (Management/Lab environment):**

- DHCP / DNS managed upstream
- Proxy access required to reach outside world
- Listed as unmanaged in MaaS subnets dashboard

**Network 2 -- 10.5.X.X -- (Private MaaS network):**

- MaaS DHCP / DNS managed here
- Nodes connected via switch with private vlan

MaaS cluster controller is running on http://10.0.X.X/MAAS/

MaaS region controller is running on 10.5.X.X

The node machines will PXE boot from the 10.5.X.X network and appear in a New state in my nodes list but fail to commission. I am seeing my nodes trying to update and install through the configured proxy, but because they are not connected to the 10.0.X.X network, it fails. Do all nodes need to be able to reach the outside world at all times? If so, how can this be configured to handle both networks?

Comment: Can you share the console output? or the error itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your comment. I ended up solving this issue by enabling ip forwarding via `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

I also needed to add the following lines under the private 10.5.X.X network interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth4 -j SNAT --to-source <MAAS IP 10.0.X.X>
post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth4 -j SNAT --to-source <MAAS IP 10.0.X.X>
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet connectivity is required on the maas pxe (managed) network.

You can set up IP forwarding using iptables to achieve this. Run the commands below. Change br-EXT to the interface connected to 10.10.x.x network and br-PXE to interface connected to 10.5.x.x network.

> /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br-EXT -j MASQUERADE
>
> /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i br-EXT -o br-PXE -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
>
> /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i br-PXE -o br-EXT -j ACCEPT